# In PowerPoint, is there a way to convert a group of objects into just one object?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I am using a tool that automatically updates PowerPoint files. The more objects that are contained in the file, the longer it takes the tool to run.

I have a file with a huge number of objects. Hundreds of freeform shapes are grouped together to form several icons. I am wondering, is there an easy way to convert these groups of freeform shapes into just one object?

The hard way is to convert the group of free form shapes to an image and replace all the groups with images, but that is kind of tedious.

Comment: Are the objects shapes?

Comment: @Raystafarian Great question! They are freeform shapes.

Comment: Can you [merge the shapes](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/combine-shapes-to-create-a-custom-shape-HA102749749.aspx)?

Comment: @Raystafarian When I combine the shapes they all change to a single color and it no longer looks like a picture.

Comment: yikes, seems like a big problem. You could try the combine `fragment` but then you'd have to go back and re-colorize them. I can't think of anything else besides the "hard way" as you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the shapes you want to "merge"
2. Copy them to the clipboard
3. Delete them or move them out of the way temporarily
4. Use the arrow next to Paste to choose Paste Special and choose PNG (right clicking does not give the PNG option)

The shapes are now combined into a single image.

Comment: When pasting, I saw two options: Use Destination Format and Picture. Picture did what you described.

Comment: How is this possibly an answer to the question..? If that's an acceptable answer then why not just take a screenshot of the fragmented shape and then just paste to PowerPoint...?

Comment: > How is this possibly an answer to the question..? Because it converts a large number of shapes to a single object, as requested.  >> If that's an acceptable answer then why not just take a screenshot of the fragmented shape and then just paste to PowerPoint. Because a screenshot would include whatever's behind/around the selected shapes.

Comment: Agreed, this eliminates any finicking you would have to do to capture just the grouped items in a screenshot.